# django-celery crontab schedule for day of month and month

Tags: django, cron, celery, django-celery

django-celery's crontab class only supports minute, hour and day of week. Is there a way to support the rest of the normal cron schedule options such as month and day of the month? Or will I need to write my own crontab class and overwrite the is is_due() method?

Answer (score 1):

This was issue [#569](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/569) and was closed on May 2012 (commit [dc6508f](https://github.com/celery/celery/commit/dc6508fdc1fb506e818cafe3ece425052637e83e)).

Params `day_of_month` and `month_of_year` were added.